# Add multiple google maps when i click add button

Tags: jquery, google-maps, symfony, twig

I'am using Symfony 2.3, twig and this plugin [location picker](http://plugins.jquery.com/locationpicker/) to display the map. I embeded a collection of addresses. Each address form has a map. The user can add the address form manually. Then google map displays correctly with the first address, but when adding a seconde address the map doesn't show up. The chrome console doesn't display any errors.

**vigilance_point_collection-prototype.html.twig file:**

```html
{% block vigilance_point_collection_widget %}
    {% spaceless %}
        {# <style>
             .remove{
                 position: absolute;
                 top: -36px;
                 right: -48px;
             }
            /* .element-div{
                 display: inline-block;
                 margin-bottom: -10px;
                 position: relative;
             }*/
         </style>#}
        <div class="collection">
            {% if prototype is defined %}
                {% set attr = attr|merge({'data-prototype': block('vigilance_point_collection_item_widget') }) %}
            {% endif %}
            <div {{ block('widget_container_attributes') }}>
                {{ form_errors(form) }}
                {% for rows in form %}
                    <div class="element-div">
                        {% set fieldNum = 1 %}
                        {% for row in rows %}
                            <div class="form-group field{{ fieldNum }}">
                                {{ form_label(row) | trans | raw }}
                                {{ form_errors(row) }}
                                <div class="col-lg-10">
                                    {{ form_widget(row) }}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            {% set fieldNum = fieldNum + 1 %}
                        {% endfor %}
                        <a class="remove btn" title="Supprimer" href="javascript:void(0)">
                            <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/custom-icon-design/flatastic-1/24/delete-1-icon.png">
                        </a>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}
                {{ form_rest(form) }}
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <a class="add{{ id }}" title="{{ 'button.add' | trans | capitalize }}" href="javascript:void(0);">
                <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/custom-icon-design/flatastic-1/24/add-1-icon.png">
            </a>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var elementCount{{ id }} = '{{ form | length }}';
            jQuery(document).ready(function () {
                jQuery('.add{{ id }}').click(function () {
                    var elementList = jQuery('#{{ id }}');
                    var newWidget = elementList.attr('data-prototype');
                    newWidget = newWidget.replace(/{{ form.vars.name }}___name__/g, "{{ form.vars.name }}_" + elementCount{{ id }});
                    newWidget = newWidget.replace(/{{ form.vars.name }}]\[__name__/g, "{{ form.vars.name }}][" + elementCount{{ id }});
                    elementCount{{ id }}++;
                    jQuery('#{{ id }}').append(newWidget);
                    $('#us3').locationpicker({
                        location: {latitude: 46.15242437752303, longitude: 2.7470703125},
                        inputBinding: {
                            latitudeInput: $('#mybook_adminbundle_outlet_addresses_0_latitude'),
                            longitudeInput: $('#mybook_adminbundle_outlet_addresses_0_longitude'),
                            radiusInput: $('#mybook_adminbundle_outlet_addresses_0_phone'),
                            locationNameInput: $('#mybook_adminbundle_outlet_addresses_0_location')
                        },
                        enableAutocomplete: true,
                        onchanged: function (currentLocation, radius, isMarkerDropped) {
                            // Uncomment line below to show alert on each Location Changed event
                            //alert("Location changed. New location (" + currentLocation.latitude + ", " + currentLocation.longitude + ")");
                        }
                    });
                    return false;
                });
            });
            jQuery(document).ready(function () {
                jQuery('.remove').livequery('click', function (e) {
                    jQuery(this).parent('.element-div').fadeOut().remove();
                    return false;
                });
            });
        </script>  
    {% endspaceless %}
{% endblock vigilance_point_collection_widget %}

{% block vigilance_point_collection_item_widget %}
    {% spaceless %}
        {% set fieldNum = 1 %}
        <div class="element-div collection">
            <div id='us3' style='width: 550px; height: 400px;'></div>
            {% for row in prototype %}
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form_label(row) | trans | raw }}
                    {{ form_errors(row) }}
                    <div class="col-lg-10">
                        {{ form_widget(row) }}
                    </div>
                </div>
                {% set fieldNum = fieldNum + 1 %}
            {% endfor %}
            <a class="remove btn" title="Supprimer" href="javascript:void(0);">
                <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/custom-icon-design/flatastic-1/24/delete-1-icon.png">
            </a>
        </div>
    {% endspaceless %}
{% endblock vigilance_point_collection_item_widget %}
```

Comment: Make sure to place the code for each of your two maps inside the load function making sure that each map used different variable names for each of the maps. Maybe you can use simple examples as templates before adding complexity to your projects: [**Link**](http://javascript.about.com/library/blgmap09.htm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I'd guess is here:

```
$('#us3').locationpicker({

... 

<div id='us3' style='width: 550px; height: 400px;'></div>
{% for row in prototype %}
```

So you have a single div which you're loading the map into.  You probably need to call the .locationpicker() constructor on a different div for each address, and to create a uniquely-named div inside that for loop for each address.  e.g.

```
$('#us{{ id }}').locationpicker({

... 

{% for row in prototype %}
    <div id='us{{ id }}' style='width: 550px; height: 400px;'></div>
```